# Comparing two sheets and highlighting the differences

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying, when the workbook is open, to store two sheets to two variables.

Then, when a value is changed in master, set the changed worksheets to two new variables and then call the compare sheets function.

The compare sheets function will compare the original Worksheet variable to the temp Worksheet variable and highlight the differences in olive green.

```vb
Sub compareSheets(shtSheet1 As Worksheet, shtSheet2 As Worksheet)
    
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim mydiffs As Integer
    
    'For each cell in sheet2 that is not the same in Sheet1, color it olive green
    For Each mycell In shtSheet2.UsedRange
        If Not mycell.Value = shtSheet1.Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
            mycell.Interior.Color = RGB(216, 288, 188)
        End If
    Next
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtSheet2).Select
    
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim master As Worksheet
    Dim eth As Worksheet
    
    Set master = Sheets("Master")
    Set eth = Sheets("eth")
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim masterTemp As Worksheet
    Dim ethTemp As Worksheet
    
    Set masterTemp = Sheets("Master")
    Set ethTemp = Sheets("eth")
    
    Call compareSheets(master, masterTemp)
    Call compareSheets(eth, ethTemp)
End Sub
```

How do I fix this error? Any ideas on how to implement what I'm trying to do?

UPDATE

I changed my code but now I get a Byref argument type mismatch in this line.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
```

Comment: That means the `ActiveWorkbook` has no worksheet with the name corresponding to `shtSheet2`. Do you have a worksheet named "masterTemp" or "ethTemp"?

Comment: do you think I should remove the " " when I Call the function?

Comment: Probably, but then your function should be rewritten to be `shtSheet2 As Worksheet`, and `For Each mycell In shtSheet2.UsedRange`. Btw, it's probably a better idea to pass `Worksheet` variables instead of `String` variables here.

Comment: Okay, check the changes I made

Comment: It looks like you are trying to color changes to the worksheets Master and Eth after it has been opened. Is that correct ? `Set master = Sheets("Master")` does not copy the worksheet to `master`, it just creates a reference. Also that reference `master` is scoped to the sub `Workbook_Open()` so is unavailable in `Workbook_SheetChange`. `Workbook_SheetChange` has the sheet and range as parameters so why not just use them ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Do you have an idea on how I could implement this better. Basically, when a value is changed in master, there will be a cell in eth that had a value that is changed also. I want to highlight the cell in master and eth to the color I have selected.

Comment: How is the change on Master made in Eth, is it a formula ?

Comment: @CDP1802 yes just a linked cell formula. That is why I'm setting the worksheet variable when the workbook is opened and then setting them after a change is made in order to compare the differences. I know that there is no event to check if a formula cell is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the opening values on the Eth sheet in an array.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim arEthOpen, addrOpen As String

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    With Sheets("Eth")
        With .UsedRange
            r = .Row + .Rows.Count - 1
            c = .Column + .Columns.Count - 1
            addrOpen = .Address
        End With
        arEthOpen = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(r, c).Value2
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Sh.Name <> "Master" Then Exit Sub
    ' color Master
    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(216, 288, 188)
    
    ' changes to Eth
    Dim arEth, r As Long, c As Long
    With Sheets("Eth")
        With .UsedRange
            r = .Row + .Rows.Count - 1
            c = .Column + .Columns.Count - 1
            If r > UBound(arEthOpen) Or c > UBound(arEthOpen, 2) Then
                MsgBox "Change to Used Range on Eth Sheet " & _
                "was " & addrOpen & " now " & .Address, vbCritical, "Warning"
                r = UBound(arEthOpen)
                c = UBound(arEthOpen, 2)
            End If
        End With
        arEth = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(r, c).Value2
        
        For r = 1 To UBound(arEth)
            For c = 1 To UBound(arEth, 2)
                If arEth(r, c) <> arEthOpen(r, c) Then
                    .Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 288, 188)
                End If
            Next
        Next
        
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING